# Overlay Screen on Oreo

Tags: java, android, overlay

I'm having an overlay problem in my application. In android Oreo, my activity is not being called to override the user's screen, when the user does certain action. How to proceed?
in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
```

Comment: Means You want to display Allow Overlay Permission Screen?

Comment: Yes, The application has a service, to stay running in the background, in the lower APIs up to 24 I can do the screen overlay, but from the android N, O is not overlapping.

Comment: Okay there is some change in SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW IN Android 8.0.

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Comment: @ChiragSavsani https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background **

Comment: update: following the oficial docs, i fix it.

Comment: Use Flag ~TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY~ to draw overlay anywhere except above the status bar. Overlay above status bar is restricted in android O